# How to protect the script, attached to my trigger in my spreadsheet, from being edited by collaborators?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script that should be triggered by editing my spreadsheet, but I do not want to let the editors of the spreadsheet to edit the script. How to arrange this?

If I just write my script in the Tools>Script Editor of my spreadsheet, and attach it to a simple or installable trigger, then every editor of the spreadsheet can edit this script  in the same way as I do (although he cannot edit the installable trigger that I attach to this script). [Google developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/scripts_google_accounts#permissionLevels) claim that I can choose editors for my script independently of the editors for the container spreadsheet:

> Initially, a script that is bound to a container, such as a Google Spreadsheet or Google Site, will inherit the permissions of the container. It is possible for a script owner or editor to add or remove users or groups from the sharing dialog, even if that means that the permissions of the script no longer match the permissions of the container.

However, I just cannot find the menu item that would be responsible for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you re-read the documentation you'll see that for container-bound scripts, such as those attached to a spreadsheet, the permissions on the script are the same as the permissions of the container. It's not possible any longer to make these different.

Comment: I am confused. I imagine the following message to google-apps-script-issues:

Comment: Sorry, I've really posted it [there](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1600&thanks=1600&ts=1342994298), because Stackoverflow comments are too short.